# Galaxy is 8 times closer 13 billion years ago?

Tags: space-expansion, universe, galaxies

Based on below,

How can I calculate the distance of a point from Earth now vs 13 billion years ago? The excerpt below claims it is 8 times further now. Can someone provide relevant equations ?

I have a question on an excerpt from the book “our mathematical universe”.

It has the passage “If our universe is 14 billion years old, how can we see galaxies 30 billion light years away? How did their light have time to reach us? Answer is we are not seeing where the galaxies are now but where they were when the light was emitted”

The next part: “Just as we see the sun as it was 8 minutes ago, We might see a distant galaxy the way it looked 13 billion years ago which was about eight times closer to the earth than now?”

Comment: Hi mn1510. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Can we make the other one non duplicate ?

Comment: Hello, if either of you have time could you please look at a question I asked yesterday. “A question about supernova explosions (decay curve) Thanks